# Error starting Angular frontend on Hyperledger Composer

Tags: angular, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I have been following the steps given in this link: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/ultimate-end-to-end-tutorial-to-create-an-application-on-blockchain-using-hyperledger-3a83a80cbc71?gi=16a30a5d90ce

I was able to successfully get the backend, REST-API, but starting angular frontend gave errors.

```
Welcome to the Hyperledger Composer project generator
? Please select the type of project: Angular
You can run this generator using: 'yo hyperledger-composer:angular'
Welcome to the Hyperledger Composer Angular project generator
? Do you want to connect to a running Business Network? Yes
? Project name: abc
? Description: sasas
? Author name: sas
? Author email: sas
? License: Apache-2.0
? Name of the Business Network card: admin@fabric-dev-servers
? Do you want to generate a new REST API or connect to an existing REST API?  Connect to an existing REST API
? REST server address: http://localhost
? REST server port: 3000
? Should namespaces be used in the generated REST API? Namespaces are used
Created application!
Completed generation process
   create app.js
   create Dockerfile
   create e2e/app.e2e-spec.ts
   create e2e/app.po.ts
   create e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json
   create e2e/tsconfig.json
   create karma.conf.js
   create manifest.yml
   create package.json
   create protractor.conf.js
   create proxy.conf.js
   create README.md
   create src/app/app-routing.module.ts
   create src/app/app.component.css
   create src/app/app.component.html
   create src/app/app.component.spec.ts
   create src/app/app.component.ts
   create src/app/app.module.ts
   create src/app/asset/images/delete_noun_cc.svg
   create src/app/asset/images/edit_noun_cc.svg
   create src/app/asset/images/failed_noun_cc.svg
   create src/app/asset/images/success_noun_cc.svg
   create src/app/data.service.ts
   create src/app/home/home.component.css
   create src/app/home/home.component.html
   create src/app/home/home.component.ts
   create src/environments/environment.prod.ts
   create src/environments/environment.ts
   create src/favicon.ico
   create src/index.html
   create src/main.ts
   create src/polyfills.ts
   create src/styles.css
   create src/test.ts
   create src/tsconfig.app.json
   create src/tsconfig.json
   create src/tsconfig.spec.json
   create tsconfig.json
   create tslint.json
   create .angular-cli.json
   create .editorconfig
   create .gitignore
   create .dockerignore
   create .cfignore
   create .npmignore
   create src/app/SampleAsset/SampleAsset.component.ts
   create src/app/SampleAsset/SampleAsset.service.ts
   create src/app/SampleAsset/SampleAsset.component.spec.ts
   create src/app/SampleAsset/SampleAsset.component.html
   create src/app/SampleAsset/SampleAsset.component.css
   create src/app/SampleParticipant/SampleParticipant.component.ts
   create src/app/SampleParticipant/SampleParticipant.service.ts
   create src/app/SampleParticipant/SampleParticipant.component.spec.ts
   create src/app/SampleParticipant/SampleParticipant.component.html
   create src/app/SampleParticipant/SampleParticipant.component.css
   create src/app/SampleTransaction/SampleTransaction.component.ts
   create src/app/SampleTransaction/SampleTransaction.service.ts
   create src/app/SampleTransaction/SampleTransaction.component.spec.ts
   create src/app/SampleTransaction/SampleTransaction.component.html
   create src/app/SampleTransaction/SampleTransaction.component.css


I'm all done. Running npm install for you to install the required dependencies. If this fails, try running the command yourself.


npm WARN deprecated browserslist@1.7.7: Browserslist 2 could fail on reading Browserslist >3.0 config used in other tools.
npm WARN deprecated hoek@2.16.3: The major version is no longer supported. Please update to 4.x or newer
npm ERR! cb() never called!

npm ERR! This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/pai/.npm/_logs/2018-10-16T12_20_55_434Z-debug.log
Application generated

     _-----_     ╭───────────────────────╮
    |       |    │      Bye from us!     │
    |--(o)--|    │       Chat soon.      │
   `---------´   │      Yeoman team      │
    ( _´U`_ )    │    http://yeoman.io   │
    /___A___\   /╰───────────────────────╯
     |  ~  |     
   __'.___.'__   
 ´   `  |° ´ Y `
```

After which I ran `npm install` manually and got this error:

```
pai@pai-Vostro-15-3568:~/fabric-dev-servers/abc$ npm install
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@3.0.11: please upgrade to graceful-fs 4 for compatibility with current and future versions of Node.js
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.2.14: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@1.2.3: please upgrade to graceful-fs 4 for compatibility with current and future versions of Node.js
npm WARN deprecated gulp-util@3.0.8: gulp-util is deprecated - replace it, following the guidelines at https://medium.com/gulpjs/gulp-util-ca3b1f9f9ac5

> fabric-dev-servers@0.0.13 prepare /home/pai/fabric-dev-servers/abc
> npm run build-archives


> fabric-dev-servers@0.0.13 build-archives /home/pai/fabric-dev-servers/abc
> gulp --gulpfile .travis/gulp.js

[17:52:19] No gulpfile found
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! fabric-dev-servers@0.0.13 build-archives: `gulp --gulpfile .travis/gulp.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the fabric-dev-servers@0.0.13 build-archives script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/pai/.npm/_logs/2018-10-16T12_22_19_281Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! fabric-dev-servers@0.0.13 prepare: `npm run build-archives`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the fabric-dev-servers@0.0.13 prepare script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/pai/.npm/_logs/2018-10-16T12_22_19_473Z-debug.log
```

My npm version is 5.6.0 and node version is 8.11.3

Comment: Looks like you've run npm install in the directory where you have installed fabric-dev-servers and not in the directory where the angular application code was generated into. Look for a directory called `abc` as that was the name you gave the project

Comment: I had saved my project titled `abc` in `fabric-dev-servers` by mistake. it is in `abc` directory @david_k

Comment: Please make sure that you installed composer-tools as **non-root user** and **globally**. https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/installing/development-tools